# How to get Google Play Services currently connected account?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Many Google Applications allow you to switch between Google Accounts and show you the currently connected account.

For example Google Fit, Gmail, Google+, etc...

From the perspective of the code I call .connect() on the Google Client and enter a loop of

- connection failed
- launch automatic resolution
- get activity result
- retry connect

until I finally connect.

This is documented in many places, here for example: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client

On the UX side what happens is that the user is presented with multiple dialogs asking every time something different.

One of the dialog ask to chose an Account between the ones available on the phone (it probably automatically resolve without user interaction if there's only one account configured).

How do you query the Google Client to know which account is currently connected?

I found no documentation about it anywhere.

The closest thing I found is this:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker

but I do not create the picker, it's something completely handled by the Play Services in the procedure I described above.

Comment: are these failures happening in Google apps? or do you want to know how the authentication works in backend?

Comment: isn't my question already answering your questions? It's Android Google Play Services. You connect the Google Client. During the connect procedure the user is asked for the account to use. I found no way to know which account the user picked and I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request the [`Account`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account) resource with Google Plus API.

Add the following permission in the manifest:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Then use [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account.html#getAccountName(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) API to get the account that is logged in currently.

**EDIT** (addressing the comment):

In `.builder` add login scope as shown in [the example](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder) and initiate the G+ Api as well. Since you do not need social scopes, this scope will give you access to currently authenticated user's information.
Once you `setAccountName` through the builder, you can access the Account resource for this user which you can get at anytime through `getAccountName`.

**EDIT 2:**

So apologies for not addressing the G+ context with last edit.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount)'s a class in simple Google Sign In (Identity platform) which give you access to account resource.
More information in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people).

Comment: thank you! I currently have no time to get back to the project where I need this but I'll try it as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi, there's no such com.google.android.gms.plus.Account in Google Play Services version 8.1.0 or 8.3.0. Furthermore this is about Google+ account. This has nothing to do with Google+. I'm talking of the Google Account.

Comment: I take the first part back, there was a problem with Android Studio, somehow didn't made me see the plus package. I tested it. I gives me the email of the connected account. But since this is Google+ API I wander if this works without forcing the user to have a Google+ Account. Any reference?

Comment: I have edited my response to address the later comment. In essence when a user has a Google account, it has G+ resources associated with it already, you just need to initiate this through the GoogleApiClient and access those resources. Please pay attention to attributions guidelines though. https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Comment: this still don't tells me if the user need Google+ for using this. I do not want to force a Google+ login. Just Google login.

Comment: Hope this is what you were looking for! :) Happy coding.

Comment: I've no google account without Google+ enabled. So I can't test this out. Creating a new google account just for the purpose of testing this seems a little too much :) this is the only reason I still didn't market yours as accepted answer. Hope someone will confirm it